# Background color change when screen is tapped

Tags: html, css, sencha-touch

I want to change the background color of particular div when touch it. I have used

```
.x-list-item:active {


background: #870000 !important; /* fallback for old browsers */
background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #870000 , #190A05) !important; /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
background: linear-gradient(to left, #870000 , #190A05) !important; /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */


}
```

above code. But when I touch the dive and pull it off, the background color still remain. after that I have used this property as this.

-webkit-tap-highlight-color

```
 .x-list-item {

    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: #870000 !important;
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: -webkit-linear-gradient(to left, #870000 , #190A05) !important; 
    -webkit-tap-highlight-color: linear-gradient(to left, #870000 , #190A05) !important; 


    }
```

But the style not apply. It means at lease not change the div color. Why is that? what is the solution?

Comment: `background` is different from `-webkit-tap-highlight-color:`

Comment: so what is the solution for it?

Comment: are you using jquery?

Comment: no. It is sencha touch library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you already have jquery library, try to use this. This will change the `background` of `.x-list-item` when clicked.

```
 $('.x-list-item').on('click', function(){
      $('.x-list-item').css({background: 'red'});
    });
```

Comment: I does not use jquery library. I want a solution without using jquery